# Incorrect link text in Careers ad

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, ios-app

I just wanted to report a small glitch. In the mobile app I see the incorrect description for a Careers ad.

When I click:

[image: screen shot from iOS app]

I get directed to another job description:

[image: description within Careers]

My guess is that the ad was maybe edited by the author to change the title, but in the app it's not updated, but it's only a guess.

**Edit 17/08**

As of today same caching issue.

[image]

Comment: Almost certainly caching.